# Regex pattern using muiltiple groups which may or may not exist with text inbetween

Tags: python, regex, string

I using Regex on a list of strings (one string at a time) in order to extract information pertaining to the string. I have a almost functioning pattern which works on all the possible events i will potentially pass into it except one. I'm fairly new to Regex and therefore i am beginning to find it impossible to handle, especially as the pattern gets more complicated. I have multiple possible strings to match, and they all work except one.

Here are the possible strings, separated by lines. The format is consistent but the content such as the names, scores and additional information are not.

```
Goal scored Sunderland 4, Cardiff City 0. Connor Wickham (Sunderland) header from the centre of the box to the bottom left corner. Assisted by Emanuele Giaccherini with a cross following a corner.
Booking Sebastian Larsson (Sunderland) is shown the yellow card.
Foul by Jordon Mutch (Cardiff City).
Dismissal Cala (Cardiff City) is shown the red card.
Penalty conceded by Cala (Cardiff City) after a foul in the penalty area.
```

They all follow the same format other than goals, and therefore work with my current pattern however i would like the goal string to also work, but it will not due to the capitalization of team names. Ideally i would like to capture the team names and score into two separate groups, home team and away team, although it is not completely necessary.

Here is my current regex pattern which, other than for goals, correctly detects the event, players names, team and any extra information after it. I initially had `.*` instead of `[A-Z]*' which worked on goals but always cut off players first names, which i believe is due to it being optional within the group.

`(?P<event>\A\w+)[^A-Z]*(?P<playername>(?:[A-Z]\w+)*\s\w+\s)(?P<team>\(.+\))(?P<extrainfo>[^\Z.]+)*`

to break this down, this is what i am trying to look for currently

the first word that appears, which is under the event group `(?P<event>\A\w+)`

any number of characters which are not a capital(initial reason goal is broken) `[^A-Z]*`

a player name, which can be be of any length (some names are singular, others have multiple parts hence the non-matched group to detect any first names) `(?P<playername>(?:[A-Z]\w+)*\s\w+\s)`

a team name which is always enclosed in brackets after the player name `(?P<team>\(.+\))`

any extra information about the event, so anything which is after the team name. I make sure to also check its not just a `.` to ensure None in the result of the matched group `(?P<extrainfo>[^\Z.]+)*`

I am currently trying to find a solution along the lines of `[^A-Z.]*(?P<hometeam>\w+[^,.])*(?P<awayteam>\w+[^,.])*` but this is not working and i am struggling.

A further task which is trivial but if possible i would love to add would be somehow removing the brackets from the teamname group so instead of `teamname (Cardiff City)` it becomes `teamname Cardiff City`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest splitting this into two tasks:

1. Extract the goals scored ([`r"^(?P<event>goal scored) (?P<hometeam>.*) (?P<homescore>\d), (?P<awayteam>.*) (?P<awayscore>\d). (?P<playername>.*) \((?P<scoringteam>.*)\).*$"`](http://regex101.com/r/gR8fE3)); and
2. Extract the other events ([`r"^(?P<event>booking|foul|dismissal|penalty conceded) (?:by )?(?P<playername>.*) \((?P<teamname>.*)\).*$"`](http://regex101.com/r/qR6kW2)).

In your example, the former matches:

```
event   [0-11]  `Goal scored`
hometeam    [12-23] `Sunderland`
homescore   [23-24] `4`
awayteam    [26-39] `Cardiff City`
awayscore   [39-40] `0`
playername  [42-56] `Connor Wickham`
scoringteam [58-68] `Sunderland`
```

And the latter, for example:

```
event   [197-204]   `Booking`
playername  [205-222]   `Sebastian Larsson`
teamname    [224-234]   `Sunderland`
```

Comment: a very simple and great solution, out of interest would changing the end to .*$ result in also collecting `.` in the case of fouls? The solution is missing the extra information group, which i am going to retain but i can add that myself without any issue. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @Excessum if you follow the links in my answer, you can play with the regular expressions and see exactly what they will do on your example.